# How to get the JSON object from both JSON array

Tags: android

how to get this array in android

first array "user" i can get but second array "userpages" i can't get help ma

my json

[image]

Comment: Post the entire json and your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONArray userArr = ...
for(int i=0; i<userArr.length(); i++)
{
    //user json object
    JSONObject userObj = userArr.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray userpageArr = userObj.getJSONArray("userpages");

    for(int j=0; j<userpageArr.length(); j++)
    {
        JSONOject userpageObj = userpageArr.getJSONObject(j);
        String title = userpageObj.getString("title");
        //....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

its because userpages is an array itself. So, fetch the array , then get data from it.

In your case:

```
  JSONArray jArr2 =jo.getJSONArray("userpages");
String title[]= new String[jArr2.Length()];;
 for(int i=0; i<jArr2.Length(); i++)
   {
      JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) jArr2.get(i);

       String title[i] = jObj.getString("title");
    }
```

Good luck :)

Comment: jo is your JSON object that you used to fetch "user!